# for fixed point combinator Y, what is \x.f(xx)

Tags: functional-programming, computer-science, theory, lambda-calculus, combinators

For the Y combinator theorem,

```
 For every function F there exists an X such that FX=X
```

what's the `F` mean here? what's the fixed point for `F(x) = x +1`? My understanding is that `x+1=x` does not have a solution?

For the Proof below:

```
For any function F, let W be the function λx.F(xx) and let X = WW.
    We claim that X is a fixed point of F. Demonstrated as follows

    X = WW
    X = λx.F(xx) W
    X = F(WW)
    X = FX
```

How's `λx.F(xx)` defined? again using `F(x) = x + 1` as example, what's `F(xx)` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in that the equation `x+1 = x` has no solution when `x` is a number. What's going on here is that `x` is not restricted to being a number; it can be a function of functions.

About `xx`: In general in lambda calculus `f x` is a function application, so `xx` is "x applied to x", or `x(x)`. Note how x is both the function that is being applied and the value being passed to it.

So, if `F(x) = x+1`, you have `F(xx) = x(x)+1`, `W = λx.(x(x)+1)`, and `X=W(W)` would be the function:

```
X = W(W) = (λx.(x(x)+1)) (λy.(y(y)+1))
```

This may seem very abstract because if you try to expand X on any concrete value you'll find that the process never ends. But don't let that bother you; in spite of that `X` is a fixed point of `F` because

```
F(X) = F(W(W))             by definition of X = W(W)
     = (λx.F(x(x))) W      using the fact that (λt.f(t))x is f(x)
     = W(W)                by definition of W = λx.F(x(x))
     = X                   by definition of X = W(W).
```

Comment: can `X` here be further simplified for `F(x) = x+1`?

Comment: You can't really simplify `X`, you can only expand it more and more. For example using just the basic fact that `(λt.f(t))x` is `f(x)` you can expand `X = (λx.(x(x)+1)) (λy.(y(y)+1))` to `(λy.(y(y)+1))((λy.(y(y)+1))) + 1`, and you can expand that further and further to get `X = (λx.(x(x)+1))((λx.(x(x)+1))) + n` for any positive integer `n`.

Comment: This is of course just restating the fact that X being the fixed point of F(x)=x+1 implies that X=X+1=…=X+n.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a bit confusion what fixed point for functions is and also about the lambda calculus notation.

First `λx.F(xx)` is a function taking an argument x and "applying" x to x and "then" "applying" F to the result, so more like `function (x) { return F(x(x)); }`, but do not take it literally, because in lambda calculus it is about substitutions of parameters and there is no order in which you need to do substitutions (what I used for simplification is *applicative* order).

So the proof rewritten to C-like syntax (actually JavaScript, as it has 1st class functions) with simple text-rewrite semantics would look like:

```
var W = function (x) { return F(x(x)); }
var X = W(W);

W(W) => (function (x) { return F(x(x)); }(W))
     => return F(W(W))
     => return F(X)
     => F(X)
```

Now back to fixed point. You give an algebraic example where fixed point does not exists... for functions it would be more like "find a fixed point of `ADD1(x) = x + 1`"

```
var F = function (x) { return x + 1; }
var W = function (x) { return F(x(x)); }
      = function (x) { return function (x) { return x + 1; }(x(x)); }
var X = W(W);

W(W) => function (x) { return function (x) { return x + 1; }(x(x)); }(W)
     => return function (x) { return x + 1; }(W(W))
     => return W(W) + 1
     => W(W) + 1
     => X + 1
     => F(X)
```

I hope that the familiar syntax made it less confusing rather than more :)

Comment: The fixed point `X = function (x){while(true)++x; return(x);}` ? an infinite loop?

Comment: Infinite loop only when evaluated eagerly... but lambda calculus is telling you neither that you need to do all substitutions nor in which order. It just gives you some identities.

Comment: In addition, the fixed point definition X = FX = FFX = FFFX ... is infinite in the same sense...

Comment: I found @jJ' 's comment about evaluation strategies really important. First met with this problem when learning the [Nix package manager](https://nixos.org/) that is configured via a **lazy** functional language (of the same name), where fixed point of functions are used to override package definitions; [this section of the Nix Pills tutorial](https://nixos.org/guides/nix-pills/nixpkgs-overriding-packages.html#idm140737319680800) shows how it is used with a lazy language that doesn't cause infinite loops. (Just understood that `fix` defined there operates on closures.)